# KendoUI Line Chart with 500+ values on datasource is lazy loaded

Tags: html, telerik, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI Line chart from Web Dataviz package for generate a Graph with 500+. but the load of the graph is too lazy. It takes like 25 seconds for the graph to be generated.

I am using a date for Category Axis and a Decimal Value for the serie with a odata datasource.

Can I optimize the load time of the graph?

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
                theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Odata/TestODataService.svc/EGauges"
                    },                      
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    sort: { field: "DateData", dir: "asc"},
                    filter: [                       
                        {field: "From", operator: "eq", value: 422 },//400+
                        { field: "Id", operator: "eq", value: parseInt(id) },
                        { field: "Intervalo", operator: "eq", value: 23 },
                        { field: "Tipo", operator: "eq", value: 'm' }
                    ],
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                legend: {                       
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "area"
                },
                series: [{
                    field: "Value",
                    name: "Value"
                }],
                categoryAxis: {
                    field: "DateData",
                    labels: {
                        visible: false,
                        rotation: -90
                    }
                },
                axisDefaults: {
                    visible: true,
                    majorGridLines: { visible: false }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true                       
                }
            });
```

Here is how the odata service is returning data:

```
jQuery1704278529312834345_1357310335401({"d" : {
 "results": [
 {
     "__metadata": {
     "uri": "http://localhost/Prosol.Web/Odata/TestODataService.svc/EGauges(18)", 
     "type": "TestOpenErpInterfaz.Web.TestEntityDataSource_EGauge"
  },
 "EGaugeID": 18, 
 "From": 422, 
 "Id": 18, 
 "Tipo": "m", 
 "Intervalo": 23, 
 "DateData": "\/Date(1357310820000)\/", 
 "Value": "3.72", 
 "TotalKw": "0", 
 "TotalCosto": "0.00", 
 "TotalKwGen": "203.23999999999999999999999999", 
 "TotalCostoGen": "16.259199999999999999999999999", 
 "FechaDisplay": "Ene 4, 2013 14:47"
},........
], "__count": "421"
}
})
```

Comment: can you paste your code to take a look at it ...

Comment: hi ... sorry to ask this but what is the shape of EGauges ... I mean what is it returning ... and also how is this Odata getting its data - is it through EF ??? have you measure on the server side how much time does this take ?

Comment: Egauges is an odata service that is returning json data collection with 421 objects. I have edited the description to show how is the service returning the data... There is not problem in the serverside, I tested the service using fiddler and it takes one second to return the data.
Also I try to separate the datasource and convert all the data into an array and then associate it to the chart data source and the problem is in the graph generation, also I test with an Stock Chart from KendoUI and the load time of it is less than 4 seconds. I cant use Stock Chart for other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Use FlotCharts, For some reason the KendoUI Chart laoad data very lazy... I use Kendo Ui Datasource for read data from Web Service and load on FloatChart...

http://www.flotcharts.org/

This is simple, fast, and freeware